# Python error with random.choice

Tags: python

I'm making a small program (quizz) to test this language and i'm stuck in a function
So let me explain
I want to receive values from my database, then use only 5 of them, so for every question, the user answer, and move to the next question until reaching the last one.
The code i have so far is

```
def escolhaFinal(id_tema, id_tipo):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT question,op1,op2,op3,op4,correto FROM questions where id_tema = %s and id_grau = %s", (id_tema,id_tipo))
    data = cur.fetchall()
    l = list(data)
    random.choice(l,5)
    for row in l:
            print(l)


    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

But i receiving this error
TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

any help regarding this function?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to be using `random.sample` instead, because that allows you to return more than a single randomly selected item from your list, like:

```
>>> import random
>>> myList = range(100)
>>> winners = random.sample(myList, 5)
>>> print winners
[79, 10, 32, 98, 82]
>>>
```

Comment: This is more logical as to what he was trying to do. And answers more than he asked, so kudoz on fixing it instead of answering it, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) you have:

> random.choice(seq)
>
> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence
>   seq. If seq is empty, raises IndexError.

To select more than one element, you can either use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
[random.choice(l) for i in range(5)]
```

Or [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to select unique elements:

```
random.sample(l, 5)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> import random
>>>
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> random.sample(l, 3)  # unique elements
[4, 2, 5]
>>>
>>> [random.choice(l) for i in range(3)]  # Note that we have 3 twice!
[3, 5, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

random.choice takes only 1 parameter. In your code

```
 random.choice(l,5)
```

what is the 5 supposed to do? The documentation states for choice: "Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq. If seq is empty, raises IndexError."

so change the line to use only 1 parameter and assign the value to use it later (aka adjust the rest of your code).